# Missing MySQL users after migration using Plesk Migration Tool

Tags: mysql, migration, plesk

so I'm not a server expert. Managed to migrate a server using Plesk's migration tool. All Plesk managed DBs were moved. But discovered that all DBs and users managed through MySQL were not migrated. Can anyone tell me a solution to this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is an expected behavior - Plesk Migration Tool will migrate only objects it knows about. Since you have some databases and users which are managed through MySQL directly, Plesk does not know anything about it, so they will not be transferred.
You should transfer such databases and users manually with `mysqldump`.
To create a backup of database with `mysqldump` you can use the following command:

```
MYSQL_PWD=`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` mysqldump -u admin DATABASE_NAME > FILE_NAME.sql
```

To restore such database run:

```
MYSQL_PWD=`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` mysql -u admin DATABASE_NAME < FILE_NAME.sql
```

Also you will need the `mysql` database which contains grant information. I do not recommend you to blindly transfer it and just re-create users.
Keep in mind that if MySQL version on target server is higher than on source you will need to run `mysql_upgrade` script to make changes in schema.

Alternatively you can export/import databases through `phpMyAdmin` which is shipped with Plesk and can be found at **Plesk > Tools & Settings > Database Servers**.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Just 1 quick question, do you know if I were to use Plesk migration again, would it overwrite all current files/DBs or would something else happen?

Comment: Yes, if you will re-migrate the content it will be rewritten.